# how to remove a colleague branch from your list of local branches in GITHUB

Tags: git, github, version-control

During a session of work, I took a look twice at a colleague branch updates using `git fetch origin` and `git checkout origin/branchname`. After looking at the branch the second time, I noticed that the branch is now part of my list of my local branches when i type `git branch` and i no longer see it among the other colleagues list of branches when i type `git fetch origin`.

The person has already submitted a pull request.

**My question**: if i use `git branch -d branchname` to delete it from my local list of branches, will it affect his branch as well?

The reason I am asking this question is that I use `git push --all` to push all changes to my local branch, and if I try to use it now i am afraid that it will display his branch among the branches.

Looking forward for any informative advice.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` works with your local refs only. `-d` deletes the local ref that represents that branch. This will not make any changes to the remote, whether the ref exists on the remote or not.

`git push --all` would push that branch if you don’t delete it, so you will need to delete it first before using `push --all`, or push individual branches without `--all`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go through official docs to understand how git works to avoid these kind of fears. Let me list out a couple of commands which will help in keeping your git repo clean.

`git branch -l` will list all your local branches which are created or checkedout from remote branches.

`git branch -d branchname` will delete only branches which are merged into head or merged with its remote branch. this will not delete a branch which is available only in your local.

if you want to delete any of your local branches irrespective of its merge status, you can use `git branch -D branchname`

`git remote prune origin --dry-run` will list remote branches which will be deleted from your local as they are deleted in remote.

`git remote prune origin` will delete all of them.

Comment: thank you. indeed you used the right word "fear". I did not want to make any big mistake.

Comment: do you happen to know why i am no longer able to see his branch among the others when i use `git fetch origin` just for a better understanding....

Comment: Probably because he deleted his branch from the remote repository.

Comment: lol, it's amazing how many experienced developers don't really understand local branches.... they see me delete my local "master" (which I do a lot) and they freak out.